# Publishing multiple messages simultaneously to Kafka patitions using multi threading for testing purpose to check the performance

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-kafka, avro

```
    import org.apache.avro.Schema;
    import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData;
    import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;
    import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
    import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
    import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
    import org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException;
    import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;

    import java.util.Properties;

 class MultithreadingDemo extends Thread 
 { 
public void run() 
{ 
     Properties props = new Properties();
     props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "xxx:443");
     props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
     props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
     io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.class);
     props.put("schema.registry.url", "xxx");
     props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
     props.put("security.protocol", "SSL");
     props.put("ssl.truststore.location", "xxx");
     props.put("ssl.truststore.password", "xxx");
     props.put("ssl.keystore.location", "xxx");
     props.put("ssl.keystore.password", "xxx");
     props.put("ssl.key.password", "xxx");
    KafkaProducer producer = new KafkaProducer(props);
    String userSchema = "{   \"name\": \"MyClass\",   \"type\": \"record\",   \"namespace\": 
      \"com.oop.hts\",   \"fields\": [     {       \"name\": \"appId\",       \"type\": 
\"string\"     },     {       \"name\": \"appName\",       \"type\": \"string\"     },     {       
\"name\": \"groups\",       \"type\": \"string\"     },     {       \"name\": \"subGroups\",       
\"type\": \"string\"     },     {       \"name\": \"jobType\",       \"type\": \"string\"     
 },     {       \"name\": \"appStartTime\",       \"type\": \"string\"     },     {       
 \"name\": \"appEndTime\",       \"type\": \"string\"     },     {       \"name\": 
 \"appDuration\",       \"type\": \"int\"     },     {       \"name\": \"cpuTime\",       
  \"type\": \"int\"     },     {       \"name\": \"runTime\",       \"type\": \"int\"     },     
 {       \"name\": \"memoryUsage\",       \"type\": \"int\"     },     {       \"name\": 
\"appStatus\",       \"type\": \"string\"     },     {       \"name\": \"appResult\",       
\"type\": \"string\"     },     {       \"name\": \"failureREason\",       \"type\": 
\"string\"     },     {       \"name\": \"recordCount\",       \"type\": \"string\"     },     
{       \"name\": \"numexecutors\",       \"type\": \"string\"     },     {       \"name\": 
\"executorcores\",       \"type\": \"string\"     },     {       \"name\": 
\"executormemory\",       \"type\": \"string\"     }   ] }\n" + 
            "";
System.out.println("schema:" + userSchema);
     Schema.Parser parser = new Schema.Parser();
     Schema schema = parser.parse(userSchema);
     GenericRecord avroRecord = new GenericData.Record(schema);
     //avroRecord.put("f1", "value777");
     System.out.println("----" + avroRecord);
     avroRecord.put("appId","spark-d0731a81f1b64f109c5d985c1b2e0011");
     avroRecord.put("appName","H@S-UCR");
     avroRecord.put("groups","");
     avroRecord.put("subGroups","");
     avroRecord.put("jobType","");
     avroRecord.put("appStartTime","2020-04-13T10:02:25.902");
     avroRecord.put("appEndTime","2020-04-13T10:02:25.902");
     avroRecord.put("appDuration",4110);
     avroRecord.put("cpuTime",337468);
     avroRecord.put("runTime",1198987);
     avroRecord.put("memoryUsage",234933352);
     avroRecord.put("appStatus","Running");
     avroRecord.put("appResult","InProgress");
     avroRecord.put("failureREason","");
     avroRecord.put("recordCount","0");
     avroRecord.put("numexecutors","25");
     avroRecord.put("executorcores","15");
     avroRecord.put("executormemory","60g");
     System.out.println("----"+ avroRecord);

     ProducerRecord<String, GenericRecord> record = new ProducerRecord<String, 
     GenericRecord>("kaas.topic", avroRecord);
     try {
         producer.send(record);
         System.out.println("Successfully produced the records to the Kafka topic : 
   kaas.dqhats.target ");
     } catch(SerializationException e) {
         System.out.println("An Exception occured" + e.getMessage());
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

   } 
  } 

 // Main Class 
 public class Multithread 
 { 
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 { 
    int n = 8; // Number of threads 
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
    { 
        MultithreadingDemo object = new MultithreadingDemo(); 

        object.start(); 

    } 

   } 
 }
```

I want to produce multiple messages to kafka partitions using multi threading .(This is needed for checking the kafka topic/partitions performance/capacity)

With the following code I am not able to produce messages to kafka partitions parallely .

Seeking for a help.

Publishing multiple messages simultaneously to Kafka patitions using multi threading  for testing purpose to check the performance

Can anyone help me in publishing multiple messages simultaneously to Kafka patitions using multi threading .

Comment: Did the answer help you in solving the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The `send()` method will only place the the message in the buffer and the messages will be sent as a part of separate thread. Essentially, that is the asynchronous nature of the producer that is exhibited.

Moreover, after the `send()` method is invoked - the `Future` object returned by this call is being ignored so you wouldn't really have any way of knowing whether your message was sent or not.

You could either try:

1. Sending the method synchronously by calling:

`producer.send(record).get();`

This will wait for the response from Kafka before moving on and you'll get an error if there are any problems in sending that message to Kafka.

Or

2. Invoke the `flush()` method after `send()`.

As the name says, this method will flush the messages in the buffer but [here is the reference documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html#flush--) for this, if you'd like to know more.

Hope this helps!